# Writing a C program that takes user input and is supposed to locate the inputted file?

Tags: c++, c, input, for-loop, io

I am supposed to use a for loop for use input
     -Not sure why a for loop? I mean all this program does is keep on asking the user to input a filename, a starting seek adds and the # of bytes to read off.

For example, the input should look like:

%myprog
Enter filename:*datafile*
Start seek:*0*
Bytes to read:*65*

My block size in this program is 20, so the output would be:

"m/n/files/program/test/datafile" block 0 read - 20 bytes
01234567890123456789
"m/n/files/program/test/datafile" block 1 read - 20 bytes
01234567890123456789
"m/n/files/program/test/datafile" block 3 read - 20 bytes
01234567890123456789
"m/n/files/program/test/datafile" block 0 read - 5 bytes
01234

So I am not sure why/how I would use a for loop to ask for user input. All we are doing is keep on asking the user to enter different files and seek ranges. The assignment does not say where to stop asking.

Comment: "The assignment does not say where to stop asking."

Hint: try harder to do your assignment :)

Comment: You could use the for-loop as an obtuse while-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop is the universal looping construct in C.

The following loops are equivalent.

FOR LOOP

```
int n;
for(n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
  foo(n);
}
```

WHILE LOOP

```
int n;
n = 0;
while(n < 10) {
  foo(n)
  n++;
}
```

Assuming you know this, you *could* write the following rather obtuse code, although it might be frowned upon:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char resp[BUFSIZ];
  for(scanf("%s", resp) ;
      strcmp(resp,"done") != 0 ;
      scanf("%s", resp) {
    printf("%s\n", resp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write something like:

```
for(int i; i<2; i++)
{
    //do your task
    i--;
}
```